# Compiling C# .net 4 code to .net 3.5?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I made a program in Visual Studio 2010 that targeted .NET 4.0 originally. However, now I need to target .NET 3.5 instead of 4.0. How can I change my target framework version to compile with an earlier version of .NET?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your code is compilable with C# 3.5 (depends on what you used), right click on your project and press on *properties*, then in application tab change *target framework* to 3.5.

Your project will be reloaded and you may now compile it

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37795/C-4-0-s-New-Features-Explained) article explains you what you should have **not** used if you want compile code on 3.5

Answer (score 3):

Go to Project Properties and select .Net Framework 3.5 under Target Framework.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Solution Explorer and have on right click on top to display properties of project.There you can change your target framework..[image]